# Specflow Specrunner does not start tests in Jenkins after Build

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2017, specflow, specrun

I am trying to run tests in Jenkins using the Specflow Framework and the Specflow testrunner.
Since I am actually just migrating to another server, I was able to copy most configurations and only had to set up a newer Java version.
Jenkins is able to build the project but stops and skips all test with the following error:

**Execution framework error: TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.SpecRunException: At least one test thread aborted. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'nameofdll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**

I am pretty sure it is actually a specflow problem, because when this error occurs locally in my VS solution, I just delete the specflow-stepmap-cache file and it works fine. Since Jenkins executes the tests there is no such file generated or I just have not found it yet.

I work with Visual Studio 2017, Specflow Runner 2.3.0, SDK 4.6. and Jenkins 2.190.2.
I know those versions are fairly old, but it worked fine on the old server and I believe there is just one thing missing.
Anyone got an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DLL is is unable to find? That can make a difference.

Comment: We also need more info about the steps in the build.

Comment: The missing library is the tibrv.dll. Can you elaborate your second question please? The build works fine, it just crashes right after the build.

Comment: Please include the configuration for the Jenkins build, and even the relevant parts of the build log. Otherwise we don't have enough information to answer your question.